# How to move GRUB to another hard disk

Tags: linux, grub, kali-linux

I installed Kali Linux on an external HD, but in the end of installation I choose to save GRUB on it. Now, every time I boot up the computer, GRUB asks for the External HD. I tried to follow some docs on internet, but I'm afraid to mess with both, Kali and Windows (on internal). Does anyone know how to do that on Kali?

Thanks a lot!

PS: My external HD is sdb and internal sda.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way, in my opinion, is to burn a copy of boot-repair-live by yannubuntu. It boots up, you connect to the internet, you reinstall the grub, and in advanced options, choose to install the grub in /dev/sdxy with whichever arguments you may wish.